# Managing error flow in AWS step-functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have an AWS step-function/state-machine of Lambda functions written primarily in Javascript (although one is in Java) and I'd like to manage the error processing better.

I have no problem with having an error condition being *caught* and then forwarded to another state in the flow. So for instance, the following state definition in my state machine passes execution to the `NotifyOfError` state where I am able to email and sms appropriately about the error state.

```
Closure:
  Type: Task
  Resource: >-
    arn:aws:lambda:#{AWS::Region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:function:xxx-services-${opt:stage}-transportClosure
  Next: WaitForCloudWatch
  Catch:
    - ErrorEquals:
        - "States.ALL"
      ResultPath: "$.error-info"
      Next: NotifyOfError
```

However, rather than hand ALL errors to this one state there are a few errors I'd like handle differently. So at first I thought that if I threw a Javascript/Node error with a given "name" then that name would be something I could branch off of in the *ErrorEquals* configuration. Example:

```
 catch(e) {
      if (e.message.indexOf('something') !== -1) {
           e.name = "SomethingError";
               throw e;
      }
```

but soon realized that name was only being prepended to the `Cause` portion of the step-function and not something that would branch. I then tried extending the base Error class like so:

```
export default class UndefinedAssignment extends Error {
  constructor(e: Error) {
    super(e.message);
    this.stack = e.stack;
  }
}
```

but throwing this error actually did nothing, meaning that by the time it showed up in the Step Function the Error's type was still just "Error":

```
"error-info": {
    "Error": "Error",
    "Cause": "{\"errorMessage\":\"Error: the message",\"errorType\":\"Error\",\"stackTrace\":[\"db.set.catch.e (/var/task/lib/prepWorker/Handler.js:247:23)\",\"process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)\"]}"
}
```

So I'm still unclear how I can distinguish errors sourced in Node that are *branchable* within the step function.

> **Note:** with Java, it appears it *does* pickup the error class correctly (although I've done far less testing on the Java side)

Comment: How did you manage to use YAML to define your state machines?

Comment: That’s the default when you’re using the “serverless-step-functions” plugin.

Comment: I’ve recently changed my build tooling so I can configure in Typescript and get the benefits of strong typing. Makes life much easier.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I get Step Functions to report a custom error and message as its `Error` and `Cause`. Note I'm using the Node.js 8.10 Lambda runtime with `async` and `try/catch`.

```js
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  function GenericError(name, message) {
    this.name = name;
    this.message = message;
  }
  GenericError.prototype = new Error();
  try {
    // my implementation which might throw an error
    // ...
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    let error = new GenericError('CustomError', 'my message');
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Note for simplicity I'm ignoring the error object from `catch(e)` here. You could also feed its `stack` into the GenericError if wanted.

This lambda function returns:

```json
{
  "errorMessage": "my message",
  "errorType": "CustomError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:33:28)"
  ]
}
```

Step Functions turns this into:

```json
{
  "error": "CustomError",
  "cause": {
    "errorMessage": "my message",
    "errorType": "CustomError",
    "stackTrace": [
      "exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:33:28)"
    ]
  }
}
```

in its `LambdaFunctionFailed` event history, and ultimately converts it again into this state output (depending on our `ResultPath` - here without any):

```json
{
  "Error": "CustomError",
  "Cause": "{\"errorMessage\":\"my message\",\"errorType\":\"CustomError\",\"stackTrace\":[\"exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:33:28)\"]}"
}
```

Comment: interesting. could have sworn i tried this and it didn’t work for me. i’ll have another look in the morning. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should return thrown exception from Lambda using `callback`. Example Cloud Formation template creating both lambda and state machine:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Stack creating AWS Step Functions state machine and lambda function throwing custom error. 

Resources:
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: "index.handler"
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
              function SomethingError(message) {
                  this.name = "SomethingError";
                  this.message = message;
              }
              SomethingError.prototype = new Error();

              const error = new SomethingError("something-error");
              callback(error);
          };
      Runtime: "nodejs6.10"
      Timeout: 25

  StateMachine:
    Type: AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine
    Properties:
      RoleArn: !GetAtt StatesExecutionRole.Arn
      DefinitionString: !Sub
        - >
          {
            "Comment": "State machine for nodejs error handling experiment",
            "StartAt": "FirstState",
            "States": {
              "FirstState": {
                "Type": "Task",
                "Resource": "${ThrowErrorResource}",
                "Next": "Success",
                "Catch": [
                  {
                    "ErrorEquals": ["SomethingError"],
                    "ResultPath": "$.error",
                    "Next": "CatchSomethingError"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "Success": {
                "Type": "Pass",
                "End": true
              },
              "CatchSomethingError": {
                "Type": "Pass",
                "Result": {
                  "errorHandlerOutput": "Huh, I catched an error"
                },
                "ResultPath": "$.errorHandler",
                "End": true
              }
            }
          }
        - ThrowErrorResource: !GetAtt LambdaFunction.Arn

  LambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole

  StatesExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - !Sub states.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: ExecuteLambda
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - lambda:InvokeFunction
                Resource: arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:*
```

Essential part is Lambda Function definition:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    function SomethingError(message) {
        this.name = "SomethingError";
        this.message = message;
    }
    SomethingError.prototype = new Error();

    const error = new SomethingError("something-error");
    callback(error);
};
```

Custom error with custom name is defined here. Of course you can also simply overwrite name (but I do not recommend that):

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    var e = new Error();
    e.name = "SomethingError";
    callback(e);
};
```

Error returned like that will be passed to Step Functions without losing error name. I suggest creating some top `try-catch` statement in Lambda Function where you would simply call `callback` with error.

Comment: I do use the callback to return the error. Also, I think in my explanation above I suggest that I tried both approaches you suggest here; am I missing something?

Comment: The important thing was `callback` call (I inserted code snippets to show that both approaches work). I do not see anywhere in your code a call to `callback`. If an exception is not catched and returned with `callback` then you will always get an `Error` in step function (that's why I pointed out that as an issue).
You can run CloudFormation template that I provided (it has no dependencies) - it will be a stable base for finding out where the issue lays (still I suspect some problem with catching exception and returning it with `callback`).